# BoxCutter and industry standard settings conflict

Tags: shortcut, external-applications, tools

When using industry standard keys, alt+lmb rotates the view. This same keyboard combo completes the operation of a boxcutter Boolean operation. Basically, you are able to start and manipulate the projected shape as long as, and until you desire to rotate the view to get another vantage point on your model. This is a problem in that the tool is completely useless with this limitation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can edit the keymap to give boxcutter a different keyboard combo for completion.

Comment: How and where? I have looked through all of box cutters shortcuts and none of them are for combo for completion. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of using “Emulate 3-button Mouse.” If you have a mouse with a depressable scroll wheel (AKA a third button), use that instead of Alt-Lmb to rotate the view as it is really standard.

Comment: The industry standard keys do not have any options for emulate 3-button mouse like the default blender keys do. Also, it defaults to alt+lmb for orbiting/rotating the view, which is industry standard in Maya.. and I quite prefer it. My goal is to use the industry standard shortcuts profile and still be able to use boxcutter. Is there no way that I can change the alt+lmb apply function within boxcutter to something like ctrl+shft+lmb?

Comment: Okay, I thus have no idea what you mean by “Industry Standard” keys, but if the orbit thing collides, it collides. Yes, you should be able to change they keymapping for the box cutter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know where the keymapping for boxcutter completion action is? I have looked everywhere and have seen nothing that remotely resembles these default actions when in the boxcutter modes of operation.

Comment: Hmm. Will look in Preferences…

Comment: Thousands of preferences in Boxcutter... but I found it. It is under "input" within the settings. Property called "Preserve Alt". There are others such as Preserve RMB and Preserve LMB as well. This changes everything! So great!

Comment: Just signed up to say thanks to @Jeff for the "Preseve " thing. Really appreciated.